# How to display battery percentage in notification bar in device with Android Nougat?

Tags: android, notifications, batterylevel, android-7.1-nougat

I purchased Lenovo K8 note mobile which has stock android Nougat 7.1.1 . i am trying to display the battery percentage instead of graphical display on the top notification bar. I found no setting to do the same. Please help.

Comment: I think you might have better luck at https://android.stackexchange.com

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site is for **programming** questions only.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code for getting battery percentage;

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    registerReceiver(this.mBatInfoReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
}

private BroadcastReceiver mBatInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
        int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, 0);
        int voltage = intent.getIntExtra("voltage", 0);
        int temperature = intent.getIntExtra("temperature", 0);
 //            batteryLevel.setText("Battery Status: " + String.valueOf(level) + "%");
 //            voltageLevel.setText("Battery Voltage: " + String.valueOf(voltage));
        double temps = (double)temperature / 10;
//            temperatureLevel.setText("Battery Temperature: " + String.valueOf(temps));

          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(level),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
}
```